# Get values of Multiple List from user and pass it in PHP for further processing

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the code and i 'm unable to find error or where i am going wrong... 
i found error "undefined index user_list"...
Basically i want to add some values in a list from user and store the whole list in database

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $abc=$_REQUEST['user_list'];
 if(isset($abc)) {
    $nabc=count($abc);
    for($i=0; $i < $nabc; $i++)
        {
        echo"$abc[$i]<>";   
        }
   }
  }
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function add_users()
 {
 var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
 var user_list = document.getElementById('user_list');
 var myoption;
 myoption = document.createElement("Option");
 myoption.text = user_name;
 myoption.value = user_name;
 user_list.add(myoption);
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form name="testing" id="testing" method="post" action="listbox2.php" />
<br>
<select name="user_list[]" id="user" multiple="multiple" ></select><br />
<br/>

<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" /><br />
<input type="button" id="add_user" name="add_user" value="Add User" 
onclick="add_users();" /><br>
<input type="button" id="delete_user" name="delete_user" value="Delete User" 
/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please ignore delete button

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed:

1. You try getting your select element with `var user_list = document.getElementById('user_list');`, but your select element has an id of `user`. These ids need to match.
2. You can add an option to a select element with `appendChild(option)`.

Example:

```
<select name="user_list[]" id="user_list" multiple="multiple" ></select>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function add_users()
{
    var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
    var user_list = document.getElementById('user_list');
    var myoption;
    myoption = document.createElement("Option");
    myoption.text = user_name;
    myoption.value = user_name;
    user_list.appendChild(myoption);
}
```

Comment: Should be  `$abc=$_POST['user_list'];` to get you rid of the undefined index error. outputting the POST variable with `var_dump($_POST)` might help you!

Comment: tried your suggestion but its not working. Can  you post what i desire??